# How to install Ubuntu server 14.04 on LVM RAID?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, raid, lvm

I want to try install ubuntu on LVM RAID logical volume, but fail on step grub installation.

There are my steps as below:
  1. use three HDDs called sda, sdb, and sdc to create a volume group.
  2. ctrl+alt+f2 switch to cmdline and create a raid5 logical volume to be "/". lvcreate --type raid5 -i 2 -L 500G -n lv vg
  3. create a logical volume 32G as swap. lvcreate -L 32G -n lv_swap vg
  4. install grub on /dev/sda, but failed. 
  error msg: Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.
             This is a fatal error.

I also tried to have one partition on each disk, and do the same procedures but still failed.
Though installation interface does not support creating LVM raid LV, I am not sure if it is allowed in installation.
Does someone have any idea to use LVM raid in OS installation?

Maybe using md raid to be LVM volume is a easy way to avoid this situation, but I still want to know if LVM raid could be used during installation process or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this guide, it seems reasonable: http://blogging.dragon.org.uk/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-raid-1-and-lvm/